# Django how to implement pagination if I have data only for a page and total pages num

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

In my app I have data only for current page and total pages num. I can request data from any page but only for one. How to implement Django pagination in that case?

for instance, I have a func which accept number of page and return this page data and num of total pages:

```
def get_data(start=0):
    if start == 0:
        return {'data': ['zero data', 'zero data', 'for zero page'], 'total_pages': 4}
    if start == 1:
        return {'data': ['second data', 'first page data', 'for first page'], 'total_pages': 4}
    if start == 2:
        return {'data': ['third data', 'third data', 'for second page'], 'total_pages': 4}
    if start == 3:
        return {'data': ['fourth data', 'fourth data', 'for third page'], 'total_pages': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

def listings(request):
    listings = Listing.objects.all()

```
paginator = Paginator(listings, 6)
page = request.GET.get('page')


paged_listings = paginator.get_page(page)
context = {
    'listings' : paged_listings
}

return render(request,  'listings/list.html', context,)
```